# Subtraindo 30 dias de uma determinada data em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como faço para subtrair trinta dias de uma determinada data, supondo-se que no campo **DT_VENC** ele informe a data de um vencimento e no campo **DT_AVISO** retorne a data 30 dias antes da informada, no formato `dd/mm/aaaa`?

Comment: é, duplicata, mas a resposta lá está igualmente ruim as que tentaram dar aqui.

Comment: coloqeui uma resposta que dá os valores corretos na outra pergunta. Seria legal se alguém desse uma olhada, por que sem nenhum voto as pessoas vão acabar usando a resposta incorreta que está aceita lá.

Comment: Opa, é isso mesmo! Obrigada.

Answer (score -3):

```
 var DT_VENC = new Date();
 var DT_AVISO = new Date().setDate(DT_VENC.getDate() - 30).toLocaleString("pt-BR");`
```